# Render spans inside pre tag (in the HTML, not displayed as text to the user)

Tags: html, css, pre

Is it possible to render spans within a pre tag?

Basically I am showing code snippets on my site, you can see them [here](https://api.blockspring.com/users/montanaflynn/blocks/b146ef8d824953134beabfa9c2716fcf).  I want to wrap some parts of the code in "span" tags.

Right now when I add `<span>` inside of the text to go inside the `<pre>`, it just renders as text, for example `My code is so <span>cool</span> and I love it`. How can I get the proper word-breaks and line-spacing of pre, while still rendering span tags?

Comment: `<pre>` won't automatically show HTML **as** HTML...you'd have to use something to escape the code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `<pre>` tag will render it's contents *literally*. You can make whitespace within another tag significant but render tags within as HTM using some CSS. For example:

**CSS**

```
.code {
    white-space: pre;

    /* If you want to use a monospace font like <pre> does by default */
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="code">
    My code is so <span>cool</span> and I love it
</div>
```

Comment: Making white-space significant in tags other than `pre`..creative! So far, I've always made `pre` tags work for me in all situations, but this is a super cool way to get around many of the small issues that you may run into when working solely with `pre` tags!